# Trying to fit my elements inside a container/wrapper using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently in the process of building a carousel for my website and I've been trying to figure how I can make my elements fit inside the container programmatically using jquery

The last element seems to overflow from the container, this due to the margins that are added to the elements. Each element has space in between. I can't seem to find the right approach in making my elements fit within.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline; }

/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block; }

body {
  line-height: 1; }

ol, ul {
  list-style: none; }

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none; }

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0; }

body {
  background-color: beige; }

.carousel-group > .carousel-items {
  margin-right: 8px;
  background: grey;
  float: left;
  height: 300px; }

.carousel-container {
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  background: teal;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .carousel-container > .carousel-group {
    overflow: hidden; }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
    
        <title>Carousel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="carousel-container">
            
            <div class="carousel-group">
                <div class="carousel-items"></div>
                <div class="carousel-items"></div>
                <div class="carousel-items"></div>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    </body>
    
    <script>
    
        var getCarouselContainerwidth = $('.carousel-container').width(),
            carouselItemsContainer = $('.carousel-group'),
            carouselItems = $('.carousel-items'),
            carouselItemsCount = carouselItems.length,
            carouselItemsWidth = getCarouselContainerwidth / 3;
    
            console.log(carouselItemsWidth + ' ' + 'Width Only');
    
            carouselItems.width(carouselItemsWidth);
        
        // Get the true width of an element with margins included
        var carouselItemsWidthTrue =  carouselItems.outerWidth(true);
            
            console.log(carouselItemsWidthTrue + ' ' + 'Width with Margins');
    
        carouselItemsContainer.width(carouselItemsWidthTrue * carouselItemsCount);
    
        
    </script>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: please provide some example of what you trying to achieve. it is not clear from your question.

Comment: Just a side note: instead of wasting your time listing all elements on your page( html, body, div, iframe etc), just use *{...}

Answer (score 4):

a. if you wanna add some style on all elements you can use:

```
 *{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     border: 0;
     font-size: 100%;
     font: inherit;
     vertical-align: baseline;
  }
```

b. about the overflow, you set the crosel item width as crousel container width / 3, but honestly the with the margin 8px*3 you get overflow of 24px. what you can do is:

```
     carouselItemsWidth = (getCarouselContainerwidth / 3) - 8;
     carouselItems.width(carouselItemsWidth);
```

or

```
     carouselItemsWidth = (getCarouselContainerwidth+24) / 3;
     carouselItems.width(carouselItemsWidth);
```

witch is the same. hope i help